# css masonry Unordered list item

Tags: html, css, masonry

i have a large unordered list that needs to be displayed in 2 columns.
i tried to make it with floats but i loose to mutch space because of the different heights of the items

then i tried the  [pure css masonry layout](http://jsfiddle.net/tQANc/1636/)

Html

```
<ul>
 <li> Airbag pentru sofer ; inteligent, airbag pentru pasager ; cu buton deactivare inteligent  </li><li> Airbag lateral in fata  </li><li> Airbag-uri cortina din fata pana in spate  </li><li> Control electronic al tractiunii  </li><li> ESP  </li><li> Servodirectie asistata electric, variabila in functie de viteza  </li><li> Asistent plecare in panta  </li><li> ABS Frana de mana electrica  </li><li> Aer conditionat automat si pe doua zone  </li><li> Sistem Audio cu RDS cu radio AM/FM ecran tactil color si ecran color  </li><li> Comenzi audio pe volan  </li><li> Conexiuni pentru AUX si USB Bluetooth pentru telefon si include streaming audio  </li><li> 7 difuzoare  </li><li> 1 ecran multifunctional tactil, 7,0  </li><li> Cruise control  </li><li> Computer de bord include viteza medie, consum mediu, consum instantaneu si autonomie ramasa  </li><li> Start/Stop  </li><li> Faruri cu cu lentile focalizante si bec halogen halogen Lumini de zi  </li><li> Oglinzi exterioare reglabile electric, incalzite si in culoarea caroseriei </li><li> Geamuri electrice fata si spate  </li><li> Insertii crom In jurul geamurilor laterale  </li><li> Stergatoare cu senzor ploaie  </li><li> Volan imbracat in piele, multifunctional, cu reglare pe inaltime si cu reglare in adancime  </li><li> Tapiterie din stofa cu piele sintetica  </li><li> Senzor presiune pneuri afiseaza presiunea cu senzor montat pe jante  </li><li> Cotiera centrala fata  </li><li> Cotiera centrala spate  </li><li> Scaun sofer individual, reglabil electric, 2 reglaje electrice cu reglaj: manual, scaun pasager individual cu reglaj: manual  </li><li> Scaune spate rabatabile 60/40 , cu 0 reglaje electrice  </li><li> Inchidere centralizata din telecomanda  </li><li> Pregatire isofix  </li><li> Jante fata si spate din aliaj , diametru 18 inchi, latime 8,5 inchi  </li><li> Anvelope fata, spate, 245 mm latime, 45% profil si rating W ; index incarcare: 96 conventionale, (date oficiale) si 18 inchi diametru  </li><li> Mase: masa maxima autorizata (kg): 2.015, masa neta (kg): 1.366, masa maxima pentru remorca cu frane (kg): 1.405, masa maxima pentru remorca fara frane (kg): 730 si EU  </li><li> Garantie: durata luni: 24, sau km: Nelimitat  </li><li> Asistenta rutiera: durata luni: 12, sau km: Nelimitat</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 2em auto;

    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 1%;
    column-width: 50%;
}

li {
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    background:#BFBFBF;
}
```

the problem is that in google chrome i don't see the bullets on the second column

in firefox the columns are displayed correct

[firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zedw5.png)

[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp7LW.png)

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a margin left to the list you will see the bullets :

```
li {
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    background:#BFBFBF;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: i don't understand why in firefox showed up ... thanks anyway

Comment: Because the default position off bullet is outside the container `li` witch is `list-style-position: outside` and there is some different compatibilities between browser see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position -- try to add a proprity `list-style-position: inside` and see the difference

Answer (score 0):

add **margin-left:20px;** in li class. It will work in both the browsers. Please do it and confirm the same.